# Is it possible to use only keycloak access token for login third party app?

Tags: authentication, jwt, keycloak, access-token

I have a keycloak and this generate to access tokens with post request. And this token save on postgredb. I want to use these tokens for authentication to a third party app. For example rabbitmq. How can i do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this official rabbitmq page https://www.rabbitmq.com/oauth2-examples-keycloak.html

 There are additional example and quick starts catering to your scenario. https://www.rabbitmq.com/oauth2-examples.html.

Once you start with implementation and face any challenges you can update the question or create new one's.